# Syncing iCal with Google calendar under 10.4?

Tags: data-synchronization, ical, google-calendar, macos

Is it possible to sync iCal on Tiger with Google calendar?

Upgrading to 10.5 isn't an option for my G5, but I'd love to be able to use iCal to access the years of calendar data I have on Google Calendar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [BusySync](http://www.busymac.com/busysync/index.html)

> Google Calendar Synchronization — Sync iCal with Google Calendar for online read-write access to your calendars from any computer, anywhere.
>
> ### Requirements
>
> - Mac OS X 10.4, or
> - Mac OS X 10.5, or
> - Mac OS X 10.6

Comment: It worked! I set up iCal so it's just subscribing to the Google calendars I have, and I have full read/write access.

Comment: Great. I'm glad this worked out.

Answer (score 0):

Before upgrading to Leopard, I used [GCALDaemon](http://gcaldaemon.sourceforge.net/) to sync calendars between iCal and Google. It isn't very user friendly and takes a bit to set up, but works pretty well once it is running.